# continue FTP download afther reconnect

Tags: c#, ftp

Is it possible to continue ftp download after reconnecting to ftp server?

Answer (score 9):

Yes.  At the protocol level, send the server "REST <seek>" before RETR to seek to a position in the file (so if you already have 1500 bytes of the file, execute "REST 1500" and it will start sending from the 1501st byte).

Here's an example:

```
TYPE I
200 Switching to Binary mode.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (140,186,70,20,223,87)
REST 800
350 Restart position accepted (800).
RETR welcome.msg
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for welcome.msg (954 bytes).
226 File send OK.
```

Comment: sorry i have now idea what to do with this code. How can i send msgs at protocol level?

Comment: +1 for answering the question at the protocol level, which is what the question asked.

Answer (score 5):

Yup, the specific command in the command line FTP client is "reget." The protocol command is RESTART (or REST), as documented about half way down the page in the [RFC959: FTP: File Transfer Functions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc959/4_FileTransfer.html) page.

The Windows command line client doesn't support it though, as Dave points out.

Comment: +1 one for answering the question that the asker wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it just depends on your client.  With plain old text "ftp.exe", no.  But if you download [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) or are using ncFTP on Unix, yes, they'll resume.