# How to resume an ftp download at any point? (shell script, wget option)?

Tags: shell, ftp, wget

I want to download a huge file from an ftp server in chunks of 50-100MB each. At each point, I want to be able to set the "starting" point and the length of the chunk I want. I won't have the "previous" chunks saved locally (i.e. I can't ask the program to "resume" the download).

What is the best way of going about that? I use `wget` mostly, but would something else be better?

---

I'm really interested in a pre-built/in-build function rather than using a library for this purpose... Since `wget`/`ftp` (also, I think) allow resumption of downloads, I don't see if that would be problem... (I can't figure out from all the options though!)

---

I don't want to keep the entire huge file at my end, just process it in chunks... fyi all - I'm having a look at [continue FTP download afther reconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177102/continue-ftp-download-afther-reconnect) which seems interesting..

Comment: I strongly recommend the python with ftplib, it is a built in library to manage ftp connections. if i have more time later i'll leave an answer. (http://docs.python.org/library/ftplib.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend interfacing with [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/) from the language of your choice.

Answer (score 21):

Use wget with:

### **-c option**

Extracted from man pages:

**-c / --continue**

Continue getting a partially-downloaded file.  This is useful when you want to finish up a download started by a previous instance of Wget, or by another program.  For instance:

```
               wget -c ftp://sunsite.doc.ic.ac.uk/ls-lR.Z
```

If there is a file named ls-lR.Z in the current directory, Wget will assume that it is the first portion of the remote file, and will ask the server to continue the retrieval from an offset equal to the length of the local file.

Comment: Fantastic! I had a 35GB Windoze image ftp download that got interrupted at 33GB and this resumed it without a hitch!!  If you need to specify authentication to the site, you can use `--ftp-user=<user> --ftp-password=<passwd>`

Answer (score 4):

For those who'd like to use command-line curl, here goes:

```
curl -u user:passwd -C - -o <partial_downloaded_file> ftp://<ftp_path>
```

(leave out `-u user:pass` for anonymous access)